# Application getting closed if javascript sends window.close() to cefsharp browser

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using cefsharp.winforms Chromium browser and I am opening a video inside the browser. There is a close button in the video. On clicking the close button the whole application is getting closed. Seems like from javascript window.close() is getting called and app is getting closed.

I have tried setting **disable-javascript-close-windows to 1** for cef flags but still the application is getting closed.
I have also tried handling **LifeSpanHandler DoClose event from where I am returning true** but that also not working.( This doesn't close the app but goodbye.html is also not appearing which I am getting as a callback)

"I expect the GoodBye html page to get open on clicking the close button. I am getting the goodbye.html callback but before that application is getting closed."

Comment: What is `goodbye.html` page exactly? `DoClose` is called after the browser has committed to closing, please read http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_ILifeSpanHandler_DoClose.htm If for whatever reason the `unload dialog` is not being displayed then you can implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IJsDialogHandler_OnBeforeUnloadDialog.htm to provide a custom one. It's important to remember that `CefSharp` is just a wrapper around `CEF`.

Comment: @amaitland goodbye.html is just a html page which I want to display on clicking the close button. I do not want the browser or app to get closed on clicking the close button instead html page should get rendered. But the problem is from javascript window.close is getting called and somehow I want to restrict this in my app side.

Comment: `OnBeforeUnloadDialog` is the first thing I'd try, or just inject some javascript to override `window.close`. Please make sure you read the links I posted.

Comment: @amaitland Setting Cef.Initialize(cefSettings) or setting BrowserSettings to Chromium browser instance is closing the application on clicking the close button. If I am not assigning the settings then close button in video is working as expected i.e app is not getting closed. Can you please tell me why it is happening so ?

Comment: @amaitland I have downloaded the cefsharp.minimal example and there also I have verified that on setting the cefsettings the application is getting closed if there is a call of window.close from javascript and if I am not setting the cefsettings then it is working fine.

Comment: I am on holiday currently, the source is on GitHub, have a go at debugging yourself.